# Pandas fill a new dataframe by interpolating data from source dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an array like `arr=[[0.5,1.0],[1.5,7.0],[2.5,5.0]]`. Which package (pandas/scipy) has methods to interpolate values at integer x values?

from
 x _ | _ y
0.5 | 1.0
1.5 | 7.0
2.5 | 5.0

to

x_|_y
1 | 4
2 | 3

Comment: And what is the condition?

Comment: @ManojK Linear interpolation. Input x are floats. output x are integer positions. if there is an integer number between Xn and X(n+1) points then compute value at integer position by linear interpolation.

Comment: Don't you want to just fit a regression model based on your input `x`, `y` and then just apply it to any new input data?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can do that

```
import numpy as np

xp = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
fp = [3, 2, 0]
new_x = range(1,3)
interp_y=np.interp([new_x, xp, fp)
```